# mariadb not allowing connection with only 1 cpu core at 95%

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, mariadb

I am inquiring about ways to allow an import and have the database accessible at the same time.

I have tried to do a 60gb mysqldump import and it only uses 1 core so it takes hours.  The storage is nvme so that isn't an issue.

The real issue is that the database can not be used by the normal users while this is happening.
I have 4 cores available and 1 is at 90%+ and the other 3 do nothing.

Are there settings to make sure the database is accessible while imports occur.